# Sending objects of information between classes to add to List<T>. Please help!

Tags: c#, list, object

I am working with two classes. MainForm and EmployeeRegistry.
In EmployeeRegistry I got a method that adds to a List (addToList).

```
public void AddToList(...)
{
   employeeList.Add(...);
}
```

In MainForm I created an object of EmployeeRegistry and I want to send
another object (with information) into the EmployeeRegistry.AddToList method to add to the list.

```
EmployeeRegistry employeeRegistry= new EmployeeRegistry();
employeeRegistry.AddToList(...);
```

How is this done (on both sides)?

Thankful for all help!

Comment: Your question is vague. Can you please explain why you can't just have your `AddToList` method take an `Employee` and add it to your ` employeeList` which is of type `List<Employee>`?

Comment: Sorry, I do not know how to explain it. But I got a List which takes objects (Employee).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this all you're looking for?

```
public void AddToList(Employee emp)
{
    employeeList.Add(emp);
}
```

And the call:

```
EmployeeRegistry employeeRegistry = new EmployeeRegistry();
Employee emp = new Employee();
// set information for emp
employeeRegistry.AddToList(emp);
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the type of `employeeList`?  In Steven's comment he's assuming `List<Employee>`, which I would assume as well.  If that's the case, then the `AddToList` method should just take an object of type `Employee`.  Also, it may be good form to overload the method with another one that takes an object of type `List<Employee>` and uses `AddRange` internally, just for later convenience.

Comment: Yes, you both assume right. But how can I code the AddToList so that it will be able to take an object as a parameter and what should I write in the body of the method?